# Webcam stream in opencv using Java

Tags: java, swing, opencv, javacv

I want to stream my webcam in my java application for some image processing stuff. I am using OpenCV and Java Library files which came along with it.

I got how to capture image, but how to capture and display frames continuously like a video.

Please suggest modification in below code or an alternative way to do so.

I m using Java Swing Application development .

```
package openc;
import org.opencv.core.*;

public class openc {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                openc window = new openc();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public openc() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
            if(!camera.isOpened()){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            else {
                Mat iframe = new Mat();
                while(true){
                    if (camera.read(iframe)){
                        System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
                        System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + 
                        iframe.width() + " Height " + iframe.height());
                        while(true){
                        Highgui.imwrite(canvas, iframe);
                        }


                    }
                }   
            }
            camera.release();

}

}
```

Comment: Highgui.imwrite(canvas, iframe); // probably won't even compile

Comment: Check JavaCV. Probably you'll get tutorial there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I got how to capture image, but how to capture and display frames continuously like a video.*

I have never used [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/info) API so I don't know nothing about this library. However I think your problem is a tipical thread-blocking issue caused by infinite loops:

```
while(true){ // infinite loop

    if (camera.read(iframe)) {
        System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
        System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + 
        iframe.width() + " Height " + iframe.height());

        while(true) { // another infinite loop
            Highgui.imwrite(canvas, iframe);
        }
    }
}
```

You have two infinite loops that are blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) causing your GUI become unresponsive. Swing is single threaded and you have to take extra care on how you create/update your Swing components.

In this particular case I think you could use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to read camera data periodically in a background thread and update `Canvas` object in the EDT. Something like this:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Mat> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Mat>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {            
        while(!isCancelled()) {
            if (camera.read(iframe)) {
                publish(iframe);
            }
            Thread.sleep(500); // prudential time to avoid block the event queue
        }            
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Mat> chunks) {
        Mat lastFrame = chuncks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        Highgui.imwrite(canvas, lastFrame);
    }        
};

worker.execute();
```

Comment: Hey thanks liked your idea, but this takes on processing time when dealing with complex image processing algorithms. Is there a way to do so using opencv only?

Comment: As I've said I don't know this API so I can't tell, but if your goal is show images/video using Swing then you'll have to deal with [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) at some point. As I see the problem you basically need two things: 1) Read data from your camera through an InputStream (that's what OpenCV does I guess). 2) Update your GUI accordingly. These two tasks can (and should) be done in separate threads, that's why I've suggested SwingWorker. @Gates

Answer (score 1):

dic19 is right, you need to encapsulate the the process of frame graping and repainting the Swing component in a SwingWorker. However I would avoid `Thread.sleep` and usage of `ImageIO`, because the actual output on the Swing component will perform poor.

So, I suggest those changes:

1.: Initialize the VideoCapture in the constructor of the SwingWorker and remove the sleep within the loop of the doInBackground() method:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    Mat webcamImage = new Mat();
    while (!isCancelled()) {
        camera.read(webcamImage);
        if (!webcamImage.empty()) {
            videoPanel.updateImage(webcamImage);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

2.: In the Swing component, that renders the image, you should use `System.arraycopy`. It is faster then `ImageIO`.

```
public void updateImage(Mat matrix) {
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if (matrix.channels() > 1) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    byte[] b = new byte[matrix.channels() * matrix.cols() * matrix.rows()];
    matrix.get(0, 0, b);
    image = new BufferedImage(matrix.cols(), matrix.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);

    repaint();
}
```

Finally, override the paintComponent() method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image == null) {
        return;
    }
    g.drawImage(this.image, 1, 1, this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight(), null);
}
```

Search [GitHub](https://github.com) for samples, I'm sure you will find something helpfull there.